# Experiencing this error on submit FormatInvalid radix-10 number (at character 1) 162.6 ^ in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, radix, formatexception

On the button I am making an API call, I get this error. What could be the issue below is my code.

```
var usersEndPoint = 'https://brotherlike-navies.000webhostapp.com/people/people.php';
      var userRequestBody = {
        'user_name': 'John Doe',
        'phone': '254724 123 123',
        'height': int.parse(height)
      };
      final response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(usersEndPoint),
          body: jsonEncode(userRequestBody));
```

I was trying to make an API call

The call failed with the above error